# test if a form input is a 1 or 2 digit integer with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, validation, integer

I have a form that has five fields that are all set to maxlength="2".

Basically, i want the only values that can be entered to either be a one or two digit integer, because calculations are performed on these fields before the values are stored in the database.

Is there any jquery that will not let a user even enter a value that isnt an integer?

Also what would be the best way to validate this with both jquery and php?  I have found some ways of doing it, but i need to make sure its secure, avoiding characters, -2, .1 etc

---

SOLVED

For the php part i used

```
if(!ctype_digit($_POST['value']))
```

which only allows for positive whole numbers

And for javascript

```
 $('.inputQuantity').keyup(function(){ 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

which deletes any entry made into the input field that is not a number.

Both above work, although i think some people prefer to use focusout(function() rather than keyup(function()   ;)

Comment: i found they best way to do it with php is ctype_digit. some of the answers below allowed for .3 or -3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

For the php part i used

```
if(!ctype_digit($_POST['value']))
```

which only allows for positive whole numbers

And for javascript

```
 $('.inputQuantity').keyup(function(){ 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

which deletes any entry made into the input field that is not a number.

Both above work, although i think some people prefer to use focusout(function() rather than keyup(function() ;)

Answer (score 2):

Testing if a string contains only one digit or two digits, in PHP, can be done with a regex :

```
// $string is supposed to contain your data -- maybe obtained from $_POST['field_name']
if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}$/', $string)) {
    // it's one or two digits
}
```

Basically, this tests for :

- beginning of string : `^`
- A digit : `\d`

  - One or two times : `\d{1,2}`
- End of string : `$`

And, in Javascript, I suppose you could use the same regex :

```
// str is supposed to contain your data
if (/^\d{1,2}$/.test(str)) {
    // it's one or two digits
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[maxlength=2]").change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   $(this).val(parseInt(val));
});
```

Haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

One theoretical newfangled way to ensure this is:

```
<input type="number" name="number1" maxsize="2" >
```

But you still need Javascript for older browsers:

```
<input name="num2" onchange="this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, '')">
```

There is no way to avoid checking it server-side anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a PHP based function specially for you --

```
<form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="textbox" name="number" />
       <input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
<?php

  $i = $_POST['number'];

  function check_number_digits($i)
  {
      $func = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $i);
      if($_POST)
      {
          if(!$func)
          {
              echo 'You entered no Number!';
          }
          else
          {
              return strlen($func);
          }
      }
      else
      {
          //Can do anything!
      }
  }

  echo  check_number_digits($i);

?>
```

I have tested and it works perfectly! Tell me if it is helpful or not.

Hope it worked!