# jQuery select by two name roots and perform one of two function depending on which root was selected

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this code to work in jQuery and I'm trying to make sure that for each iteration of each root element, its alternate root element for that same iteration doesn't contain anything.  Otherwise it sets the .val("") property to an empty string.  Looking for a simple solution if possible using search, find, or swap.

Each matching number is on the same row level and the same iteration count.

I have two input types of input text elements with two different root names like so:

1st Root is "**rootA**"

```
 
    <input type="text" name="rootA1" />
    <input type="text" name="rootA2 />
    <input type="text" name="rootA3" />
```

2nd Root is "**rootB**"

```
 
    <input type="text" name="rootB1" />
    <input type="text" name="rootB2 />
    <input type="text" name="rootB3" />
```

On blur if any of rootA is called call function fnRootA();.
On blur if any of rootB is called call function fnRootB();.

Again, I'm trying to make sure that for each iteration like 1 that the alternate root doesn't contain anything, else it sets the .val("") property to an empty string of the root being blurred.

My current code works for a single element but wanted to use find or search but not sure how to construct it..

```
$("input[name='rootA1']").blur(function(e) {
   fnRootA(1); // this code just removes rootA1's value val("") 
              //if rootB1 has something in it value property
             // the (1) in parenthesis is the iteration number
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add a class `rootA` and `rootB` to your inputs? It will make your life a lot easier

Comment: Put that as your answer please.

Comment: @hsalama you could do that but it's not necessary at all, attribute contains selector is easy enough I'd say :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

the **^** selector selects all the elements that start's with name = root

```
$('input[name^=root]').on('blur', function(){

    if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('rootA') > -1){

       fnRootA();
    }
    else{
        fnRootB();
    }

})​;​
```

Comment: This should work; to get the number, one could use `+this.name.match(/\d+/)[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). It selects all `rootA`/`rootB` inputs.

Like this:

```
$("input[name*='rootA']").blur(function(e) {
    //execute rootA function
});

$("input[name*='rootB']").blur(function(e) {
    //execute rootB function
});
```

(to get the number of an input you can just use string.replace to eliminate the root prefix)

Comment: How would I ask this question to find an answer on stack overflow or google?  Just curious what lingo to use.

Comment: Maybe something like `select input elements with common prefix`. Nothing too special :)

Answer (score 1):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FKMd6/)

It looks to me like we are trying to find matching rootB# inputs, easiest way is to just grab the current name of the rootA we're grabbing and get the # following, then call the function with that number and delete the corresponding rootB# value.

```
$('input[name^="rootA"]').blur(function(e) {
    var _name = $(this).attr('name');

    _name = _name.substr(5);
    fnRootA(_name); 

});

function fnRootA(num) {
    console.log(num);

    $('input[name="rootB' + num + '"]').val('');
}
​
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `_name` is global here, and a string rather than a number.

Comment: There's nothing here that wouldn't work in IE8, what seems to be the issue?

Comment: console was undefined.  It works to a degree, but not if the numbers are larger than a single digit.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah removed console.log (that is for all other browsers) It will work with any size number also, substr takes from the 5th character on to however large it is

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE**

Hmmm. A little broad in your explanation, but I'll take a stab at it.

> *The following will grab all inputs of "rootA" and tell them "hey, on blur make all "rootB" elements go string.empty!"*

```
$("input")
    .filter(function(e) {
        //  This should basically get a jQuery object made up of all input elements whose tag name contains "rootA"
        return $(this).attr("name").indexOf("rootA") != -1;
    })
    .blur(function(e) { //  of course the onblur function
        $("input")
            .filter(function(e) {
                //  This should basically get a jQuery object made up of all input elements whose tag name contains "rootB"
                return $(this).attr("name").indexOf("rootB") != -1;
            })
            .val("");   //  this would set their values to ""
    })
```

> *Could also be written*

```
$("input[name*='rootA']")
    .blur(function(e) {    //    of course the onblur function
        $("input[name*='rootB']")
            .val("");    //    this would set their values to ""
    })
```

> ***HOWEVER*** If you wanted to change ALL inputs not on the same ROOT as the inputs currently selected you could use the following

```
$("input")
    .blur(function(e) {    //    of course the onblur function
        // Grab the root name without Number for purpose of knowing what inputs NOT to reset
        var rootName = $(this).attr("name").substring(0, 5);
        $("input")
            .filter(function(e) {
                //    This should basically get a jQuery object made up of all input elements whose tag name contains "rootB"
                return $(this).attr("name").indexOf(rootName) == -1;
            })
            .val("");    //    this would set ALL inputs not of current root name values to ""
    })
```

## FULL WORKING EXAMPLE WITH RESET BUTTON HERE

Answer (score 1):

If you add a class to your inputs like `class = 'rootA'` to the first three and `class='rootB'` to the other three, you can do this

EDIT: using hasClass as suggested by @pimvdb

```
$('input').on('blur', function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('rootA'))
    alert('rootA')
   else if($(this).hasClass('rootB'))
        alert('rootB')
```

})

See live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rceLE/1/)

Comment: Note that this checks exact class matches. `hasClass` may be more appropriate.

Comment: If both of these inputs had the same format like a money format would just keep the same exact format in css but have two different names?

Comment: @RetroCoder can you elaborate? The name of the input would be irrelevant to your select since I am grabbing all inputs and then checking their class.

Comment: @hsalama, I didn't realize you don't have to have an actual css selector class with properties defined.  All you needs is add the class name to the element with no formatting. Weird.

Comment: Only problem I'm having now is determining the index. Any recommendations?

Comment: i'm using this to retrieve the number if any: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512471/test-if-a-form-input-is-a-1-or-2-digit-integer-with-jquery-and-php

Comment: @RetroCoder I thought all three input would call a single function so you would not care if it was `rootA1` or `rootA2` that fired the `blur` event, you'd call the same function! Isn't that the case?

Comment: Same index only must check its alternate ... but very simple with your soln. if I use that link and parseInt.